# Хранение настроек независимо от версии приложения

Tags: c#, настройка

В C# настройки приложения хранятся в Application Data по пути, например как у меня:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Local Settings\Application Data\ControlFilesSender\
```

Всё-бы хорошо, но как только появляется новый билд приложения изменяется каталог хранения настроек на примерно следующий:

```
ControlFilesSender.exe_Url_zoeduys2g2ptf0lawplhuzw35lqtw02k
```

Как это вылечить? Хочется хранить настройки в одном каталоге, это тупо не удобно даже при разработке, билды часто меняются и каждый раз при запуске приложения необходимо переконфигурировать, а учитывая что почти каждый день приходится эти версии вводить в эксплуатацию и на десятке компов переконфигурировать приложение снова... геммор в общем.
Если кто знает лёгкое решение - подскажите, умоляю! Рылся в сторону SettingsProvider - так и не разобрался что с ним делать. Если есть у кого ссылки на разжеванный How-To по нему - очень буду рад почитать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Менять алгоритм, по которому работают `Settings` — не лучшая идея. Вот [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rprabhu/client-settings-faq) описано, как работают `Settings` и почему.

---

По сути, вам просто нужно не терять старые значения настроек при выходе новой версии.

Для этого, по идее, надо просто вызвать метод:

```
Settings.Default.Upgrade();
```

Вот [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) к нему.

Этот вызов попытается найти предыдущие установки и импортировать их.

Comment: Понял, но тогда мне придётся где-то хранить информацию о том выполнял-ли я Upgrade() или нет? (@cyberdream это тоже я только на работе :) )

Comment: @demol0cv, @cyberdream: В [этой статье](http://www.ngpixel.com/2011/05/05/c-keep-user-settings-between-versions/) советуют такой трюк:

1. Создаёте в свойствах поле `NeedUpgrade` со значением `false`.
2. Пользуетесь таким кодом:

    var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
    if (settings.NeedUpgrade)
    {
        settings.Upgrade();
        settings.NeedUpgrade = false;
        settings.Save();
    }

3. При выходе новой версии устанавливаете `NeedUpgrade` в `true`.

Comment: Одним словом Needupgrade должен быть по умолчанию true при разработке, а все остальные настройки будут тащиться из предыдущих версий? Клёво :) Спасибо! Завтра отмечу как принятый :)